# JFrame layout helping/guide,

Tags: java, swing, jframe, layout-manager, grid-layout

I am having trouble with the layout of my JFRAME
the layout is extremely difficult to me because i have just started learning it.
the layout I'm looking for is 
select data        START 
DAY: "textField"
Month: "textField"
YEAR: "textField" 
END DATE
DAY: "textField"
Month: "textField"
YEAR: "textField"

like it is in the end stage, why isn't top working

[image: JFRAME]

The below code shows the image above

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class TopUpHistoryScreen extends JDialog {

    private JPanel mainPanel;
    private JTextArea historyScreen;    

    public TopUpHistoryScreen()
    {
        setPanels();

        setModalityType(ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        setSize(600, 600);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public void setPanels()
    {
        mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 2));
        JPanel containerPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        JPanel lowerPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        //JButton apply = new JButton("Select data area");
        JButton exit = new JButton("Okay!");
        exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                dispose();
            }
        });
        JButton checkDate = new JButton("check dates");

        JLabel SelectData = new JLabel("Select data area\n");
        JLabel START = new JLabel("START DATE!");
        JLabel startDay = new JLabel("Day:");
        JTextField sDay = new JTextField();

        JLabel startMonth = new JLabel("Month:");
        JTextField sMonth = new JTextField();

        JLabel startYear = new JLabel("Year:");
        JTextField sYear = new JTextField();

        JLabel END = new JLabel("END DATE!");

        JLabel endDay = new JLabel("Day:");
        JTextField eDay = new JTextField();

        JLabel endMonth = new JLabel("Month:");
        JTextField eMonth = new JTextField();

        JLabel endYear = new JLabel("Year:");
        JTextField eYear = new JTextField();

        JTextField Data = new JTextField();
        JTextField touchOnTimeFieldminute = new JTextField();

        historyScreen = new JTextArea(5,30);
        JScrollPane scrolll = new JScrollPane(historyScreen);

        mainPanel.add(SelectData);
        mainPanel.add(START);
        mainPanel.add(startDay);
        mainPanel.add(sDay);
        mainPanel.add(startMonth);
        mainPanel.add(startYear);
        mainPanel.add(sYear);
        mainPanel.add(END);
        mainPanel.add(endDay);
        mainPanel.add(eDay);
        mainPanel.add(endMonth);
        mainPanel.add(eMonth);
        mainPanel.add(endYear);
        mainPanel.add(eYear);
        mainPanel.add(checkDate);
        //mainPanel.add(touchOnTimeFieldhour);
        //mainPanel.add(SelectData);
        //mainPanel.add(touchOnTimeFieldminute);
        //mainPanel.add(touchOnTimem);
        lowerPanel.add(scrolll);
        lowerPanel.add(exit);
        //lowerPanel.add(apply);
        //touchOnTimeFieldhour.setSize(10,10);
        containerPanel.add(mainPanel);
        containerPanel.add(lowerPanel);

        add(containerPanel);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the `mainPanel.add(component);` sequence in `setPanels()` method to the following..

```
    mainPanel.add(SelectData);
    mainPanel.add(START);
    mainPanel.add(startDay);
    mainPanel.add(sDay);
    mainPanel.add(startMonth);
    mainPanel.add(sMonth);
    mainPanel.add(startYear);
    mainPanel.add(sYear);
    mainPanel.add(END);
    mainPanel.add(new JLabel());
    mainPanel.add(endDay);
    mainPanel.add(eDay);
    mainPanel.add(endMonth);
    mainPanel.add(eMonth);
    mainPanel.add(endYear);
    mainPanel.add(eYear);
    mainPanel.add(checkDate);
```

and it will work..as you are using `GridView` to `mainPanel`, the elements will get the position according to the sequence you are adding it to `mainPanel`...

Comment: Thank you, doesn't have to look neat yet just testing this out. THIS JFRAME LAYOUT, and stuff is so difficult, to get right, i enjoy the system.out.prinln(); days HAHA